How to load model tensorflow lite with ASP.NET Core
I want to use .tflite in .NET. I tried to search how to do this on the internet, but I can't find any way.
Can you give me code to load my .tflite in .NET?
If .NET can load model .tflite, can I deploy my .tflite model to the cloud and can .NET load it?
My UI using Flutter and backend is using .NET. I the way is convert .tflite to .tf but I don't want to do that (only as a last resort)
This is the code ChatGPT provided, but I think it is wrong:
using System;
using System.IO;
using TensorFlowLite;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string modelPath = "path/to/your/model.tflite";

        using (var interpreter = new Interpreter(modelPath))
        {
            interpreter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}


There are many good libraries to work with tensorflow models in C#, like:TensorFlowSharp,TensorFlow.NET.
